# How to install docker-compose on Alpine Linux 3.13

Tags: linux, rust, docker-compose, alpine-linux

I'm trying to install docker-compose on Linux alpine 3.13 following the documentation at https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/

But when I try to install rust it throws the following error:

> ERROR: unable to select packages:
> so:libLLVM-11.so (no such package):
> required by: rust-1.51.0-r0[so:libLLVM-11.so]

Anyone have any idea of how to fix this?

Comment: `apk add --no-cache llvm11-libs`: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=libLLVM-11.so&path=&name=&branch=edge

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it didn't work.
 
`/app # apk add --no-cache llvm11-libs`

fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz

fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz

fetch http://dl-2.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz

`ERROR: unable to select packages:
  llvm11-libs (no such package):
    required by: world[llvm11-libs]`

Comment: Did you particularly want to install from Docker? If not, from Alpine >= 3.10 you should be able to just `apk add docker-compose`.

Comment: Yes, I particularly want to install docker-compose inside docker:dind image.

And `apk add docker-compose` doesn't work there

Comment: @CaioBorghi Could you share your Dockerfile? This seems to work:
`FROM docker:dind`; `RUN apk add --update docker-compose`

Comment: @CaioBorghi it errors cause you are on Alpine 3.13 when the package is only on the edge version. Either use the `alpine:edge` image or use `apk add --no-cache --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main llvm11-libs`

Answer (score 2):

Since alpine 3.10, if you are in the container:

```
apk add --update docker-compose
```

Otherwise, on the dockerfile:

```
RUN apk add --update docker-compose
```

Note that this does not install docker, you should have it installed already

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Alpine 3.13, you can also search for the packages on the official [site](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86/llvm11-libs).

```sh
apk add llvm11-libs --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main
```